# How to fix "'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data." Error?

Tags: python, time-series, statistics, prediction, forecast

When I try to predict the results using ARIMA for a specific train/test split, its throwing an error like this:

"*'The `start` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data*"

This the code i have been trying:
`pred0 = results.get_prediction( start = '2019-06-20', dynamic=False)`

Same happens for `get_forecast()` method.

Comment: What package are you using? Can you share enough code to replicate the error?